# Replacing an index with two values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing

I'm attempting to solve the following problem in Matlab:

> The   function `replace_me` is defined like this: `function w = replace_me(v,a,b,c)`. The first input argument `v` is a vector,    while `a`,`b`, and `c` are all scalars. The function replaces  every element of `v` that   is equal to `a` with `b` and `c`.
>
> For example, the command
>
> ```
> x = replace_me([1 2 3],2,4,5);
> ```
>
> makes `x` equal   to  `[1 4 5 3]`.  If `c` is omitted, it replaces occurrences of `a` with two copies of `b`. If `b` is   also    omitted, it replaces each `a` with two zeros."

Here is what I have so far:

```
function [result] = replace_me(v,a,b,c)
    result = v;
    for ii = 1:length(v)
        if result(ii) == a
            result(ii) = b;
            result(ii +1) = c;
        end
    end
end
```

The function replaces the values in `v` that are the same as `a` with `b`, but I'm not able to replace `a` with both `b` and `c`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

I have updated my code:

```
function [v] = replace_me(v,a,b,c)
for ii = 1:length(v)
  if v(ii) == a
    v = horzcat(v(1:ii-1), [b c], v(ii+1:end));
    fprintf('%d',v);
  elseif v(ii) == a && length(varargin) == 3
    v = horzcat(v(1:ii-1), [b b], v(ii+1:end));
    fprintf('%d',v);
  elseif v(ii) == a && length(varargin) == 2
    v = horzcat(v(1:ii-1), [0 0], v(ii+1:end));
    fprintf('%d',v);
  else

      fprintf('%d',v);
  end

end
end
```

I receive the following error when I try replace_me([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10], 2, 2):

> > replace_me([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10],2,2)
> >         12345678910
> >         Error using replace_me (line 4)
> >         Not enough input arguments.

Comment: you algorithm is wrong, please try mine, you don't take into account that the vector increase his size while traversing it. Besides that, if you want to use a variable number of arguments you should use `varargin`, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). If you like my answer please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an alternative:** (Originally [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991725/2111163) by @A. Donda)

This has the advantage of **replacing multiple occurrences**

```
function [result] = replace_me(v,a,b,c)
    if nargin == 3
        c = b;
    end
    if nargin == 2
        c = 0;
        b = 0;
    end
    result = v;
    equ = result == a;
    result = num2cell(result);
    result(equ) = {[b c]};
    result = [result{:}];
end
```

**Results:**

```
>> x = replace_me([1 2 3],2,4,5)

x =

 1     4     5     3

>> x = replace_me([1 2 3],2)

x =

 1     0     0     3

>> x = replace_me([1 2 3],2,4)

x =

 1     4     4     3

>> x = replace_me([1 2 3 2], 2, 4, 5)

x =

 1     4     5     3     4     5
```

Comment: Just curious how I would deal with input values that are omitted. I still have to deal with this portion of the problem:

"If c is omitted, it replaces occurrences of a with two copies of b. If b is also omitted, it replaces each a with two zeros."

Is there a way to use the nargin keyword to deal with a missing value for b and/or a missing value for c in the input?

Answer (score 2):

By counting the number of times that `a` appears in `v` you can calculate the size of your resulting vector `length(v) + sum(v == a)`, then you can iterate over the vector and insert `[b c]` each time you find a match. You should increment the counter `ii` by two each time you insert new elements, otherwise if `a=b` you'll fill the remaining part of the vector with `a`'s. It's not an efficient algorithm but it similar to your implementation

```
result = v;
rep = sum(result == a);

if rep == 0
  return
end

for ii = 1:(length(result) + rep)
  if result(ii) == a
    result = [result(1:ii-1), [b c], result(ii+1:end)];
    ii = ii + 2;
  end
end
```

an efficient alternative (without vector resizing) could be:

```
rep = sum(v == a);

if rep == 0
    result = v;
    return;
end

result = zeros(1, length(v) + rep);

idx = 1;
for ii = 1:length(v)
    if v(ii) == a
       result(idx) = b;
       result(idx+1) = c;
       idx = idx + 2;
    else 
       result(idx) = a;
       idx = idx + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation to your answer for the OP?

Comment: I receive a warning message: `idx` might be used incompatibly or redefined.

Comment: I used the `+=` operator, which is not valid in matlab, answer edited

Answer (score 1):

Can be like this:

```
function result = replace_me(v, a, b, c)
  result = [];
  for ii = 1:length(v)
    if v(ii) == a
      result = [result, b, c];
    else
      result = [result, v(ii)];
    end
  end
end
```

About the error "Error using replace_me (line 4) Not enough input arguments.", it is simply because you wrote the function with 4 input arguments while you called with only 3.

Comment: your code is wrong, test it with `v = [3 4 1 2 3 1]`, `a = 1`, `b = 2` and  `c = 2`, you don't take into account that the vector increase his size each time you find a new match

Comment: I want to increase the vector size each time I find a match. Since a is replaced with both b and c, the the vector size would grow by 1 for instance that a is equal to an index value of v.

Comment: sorry, i thought you have to check for only 1 index. I edited the code as well.

Comment: How to preallocate result in this case without knowing the length of result on the first hand?